# Ext3 Journaling Question on inode and disk layout

Tags: linux, filesystems, ext3, journaling

I have the following questions about Journaling and JBD(journaling block device):

1. Why Journal Inode number comes as 8 when we do ./dumpe2fs?
2. Where on disk partition do we store journaled blocks?

Below is what ./dumpe2fs shows:

`Journal inode: 8 Journal size: 128M Journal length 32768 Journal Start: 0 Journal Sequence: 0x00000001`

Comment: This is answered at e.g. http://askubuntu.com/a/14860/383994